# iTextSharp: Add named destination to existing pdf based on bookmarks

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a huge, generated PDF file (huge = a couple thousand pages) in which I want to jump into. I cannot jump to pages using `a.pdf#page=123`since the page number might change and I do not want to manage the page number references. So I want to create named destinations in that PDF to jump to. Those destinations will be based on bookmarks, which are created by the generating process. I have no trouble, accessing and parsing the bookmarks. But I can't seem to find the right combination of method calls to create a named destination.

I looked at different articles and posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734965/add-named-destination-to-pdf-using-itextsharp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884833/add-named-destinations-to-an-existing-pdf-document-with-itext) or even on [itextpdf.com/examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/2179#1367-addnameddestinations.java)), but still no success. Here is what I tried:

```
using(var reader = new PdfReader(sourcePath))
using(var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(drainPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    var dest1 = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 57, 575, 0);
    var page = reader.GetPageOrigRef(18);
    dest1.AddPage(page);
    stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestination("123", 18, dest1);

    var dest2 = new PdfDestination("18 XYZ 57 575 0");
    stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestination("124", 18, dest2);

    var dest3 = new PdfDestination("18 XYZ 57 575 0");
    page = reader.GetPageOrigRef(18);
    dest3.AddPage(page);
    stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestination("125", 18, dest3);

    var map1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "126", "18 XYZ 57 575 0" } };
    stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestinations(map1, 1);

    var map2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "127", "18 /XYZ 57 575 0" } };
    stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestinations(map2, 1);

    var dest4 = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ);
    page = reader.GetPageOrigRef(18);
    dest4.AddPage(page);
    stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestination("128", 18, dest4);
}
```

But when I try to read the destinations from the changed file, I don't get any destinations back... I tried multiple ways to get them:

```
  using (var reader = new PdfReader(drainPath))
  {
    ICollection namedDests = reader.GetNamedDestination();
    ICollection namedDestsName = reader.GetNamedDestination(true);
    ICollection namedDestsNoName = reader.GetNamedDestination(false);

    ICollection simpleDestName = SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(reader, true);
    ICollection simpleDestNoName = SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(reader, false);

    ICollection fromNames = reader.GetNamedDestinationFromNames();
    ICollection fromNamesTrue = reader.GetNamedDestinationFromNames(true);
    ICollection fromNamesFalse = reader.GetNamedDestinationFromNames(false);

    ICollection fromStrings = reader.GetNamedDestinationFromStrings();

    var sum = new[]
    {
      namedDests, namedDestsName, namedDestsNoName,
      simpleDestName, simpleDestNoName, fromNames,
      fromNamesTrue, fromNamesFalse, fromStrings
    }.Sum(i => i.Count);

    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, sum);
  }
```

But the sum remains 0 and this test fails. I even walked the extra mile and tested my destinations in firefox, opening the file from `drainPath` and appending `#namedDest=123` (124,125 and so on) but no success...

So at this point, I'm pretty certain, that no destinations have been added to that PDF.

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.10 and my source PDF has 30 pages, making the destination at page 18 valid.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this?